# ng-repeat is showing duplicates in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, duplicates, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have `ng-repeat` loop

```
ng-repeat="car in CarsData| orderBy:car_id | startFrom: (ItemPerPage * (CurrentPage - 1)) | limitTo:9 ">
```

This is showing duplicated listings.
How can i remove duplicate listing? Please check the home page of CarSangrah.com

Comment: try this ng-repeat="car in CarsData track by $index ....

Comment: Try putting the order by filter last, might also consider track by.

Comment: track by $index is not working

Answer (score 0):

you can use track by to solve the problem
`track by $index` or `track by id`

You can get more details from this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates)